# Error while retrieving values from C# Thread callback

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the following piece of code to generate two threads as below in Method2

```
Thread[] arrThreads = new Thread[2];

Thread t1 = new Thread(() =>
{
    value1 = this.Method1(<some params>);
});
t1.Start();
arrThreads[0] = t1;

Thread t2 = new Thread(() =>
{
    value2 = this.SomeOtherMethod(<some params>);
});
t2.Start();
arrThreads[1] = t2;

// Code which waits for both threads to get over OR for a threshold, whichever comes first!
```

This works fine on my dev.  But on release to IIS production machine, following error is encountered.

```
    at System.Data.RBTree`1.GetNodeByIndex(Int32 userIndex) 
    at System.Data.RBTree`1.get_Item(Int32 index) 
    at System.Data.DataRowCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) 
    at Namespace.Class.Method1(params) in D:\XXXX\Class.cs:line 11309 
    at Namespace.Class.<>c__DisplayClasse.<Method2>b__a() in D:\XXXX\Class.cs:line 11687 
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData) 
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData) 
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Can anyone help me out with this error please?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the `.Message` of the exception? you're showing the stacktrace, but not the message

Comment: Here is what the IIS Administrative Events have logged

    An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated. 

    Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/8/ROOT Process ID: 2756 

    Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException 
    Message: There is no row at position 0.

Comment: I can see 2 possibilities: 1) Your code does not deal with an empty resultset correctly, 2) Your 2 methods are not independent and try to use shared data incorrectly.

Comment: Either way you should be using Task or ThreadPool, not Threads.

Comment: @HenkHolterman meh, not sure we have enough information to say that

Comment: The problem isn't in the way you're starting the threads. The problem is in the code that the threads are running. You need to show us that if you want an answer that's more than a guess.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check what is happening in `Namespace.Class.Method1`, in `D:\XXXX\Class.cs:line`, on-or-about (sometimes the line number tracking gets a little screwy) 11309. I expect it will be doing something like:

```
var row = someDataTable.Rows[0];
```

At this point, there *are no rows* - perhaps a query returned no data for some reason (check the query). It is also theoretically possible that this is related to unsynchronized threading concerns (since you start two threads), or a race condition - but again: we don't have enough context for that. Until then, there is no reason to presuppose that this relates to multi-threading, but it is something to keep in mind as a possibility if you have multiple threads mutating the same state data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

What **Method1** really has on line 11309 is a simple **}** ( An end of function curly brace).  Also the above stack trace and message is from the Event Viewer Administrative Events.

Let me also point out the my application pool has 4 worker processes.

Comment: These two methods fetch fairly different objects and don't as such change the same state as you mentioned.

Comment: @JunaidKirkire the worker processes is unrelated; and if the methods are working on different objects, then multi-threading is a red herring. Like I said, the line number can be "on-or-about" - somewhere in that method there is something access a row in a data-table by index (row `0`, either explicitly `0` or in a `for` loop). The problem here is your code - you need to see why that table is empty, and fix it.